# How to add an anonymous block with this code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A junior SQL developer was trying to write an anonymous block to but is running into issues. The code should count how many items a person can afford based on their budget.  The are sure that the SQL works fine, and their logic for counting the number of products is OK, but they don’t remember the right syntax for creating an anonymous block. Help them by finding and fixing the three errors in the following PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE

firstName VARCHAR(50) := 'Rob';

budget NUMBER = 600;

counter NUMBER;

CURSOR all_products AS

        SELECT product_name, list_price FROM oe.PRODUCT_information;



counter := 0;

FOR items IN all_products LOOP

     IF (items.LIST_PRICE <= budget) THEN
          counter := counter + 1;
     END IF;
END LOOP;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(firstName || ', you can afford ' || TO_CHAR(counter) || ' items.');
END;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not just give the junior programmer a link to [the Oracle PL/SQL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002)?

Answer (score 1):

Two *minor* mistakes:

- `DECLARE` should go first, `BEGIN-END` next
- you missed colon sign for the `BUDGET` variable

Test case:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table product_information (product_name varchar2(20), list_price number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into product_Information values('Some product', 100);

1 row created.
```

Your code, fixed:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    firstname   VARCHAR(50):= 'Rob';
  3    budget      NUMBER := 600;       -- missing colon
  4    counter     NUMBER;
  5  cursor all_products is
  6    SELECT product_name,
  7           list_price
  8    FROM product_information;        -- I removed OE. (as I don't have that schema)
  9
 10  BEGIN
 11    counter := 0;
 12    FOR items IN all_products LOOP
 13      IF(items.list_price <= budget)THEN
 14        counter := counter + 1;
 15      END IF;
 16    END LOOP;
 17
 18    dbms_output.put_line(firstname
 19                         || ', you can afford '
 20                         || TO_CHAR(counter)
 21                         || ' items.');
 22  END;
 23  /
Rob, you can afford 1 items.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```